# Find what starts on login

Tags: gnome, startup, startup-applications

What are all the places where things can start from, at login of Ubuntu (Gnome)?

There's an application that crashes every time I log in and I want to remove it (but not the application itself because it runs fine when started manually; the startup is probably some updater)

- It's not in Gnome's "Startup Applications"
- `crontab -e` of administrator and user are both empty
- It's not in `snap`

Could it be other cron jobs scheduled to run on each login? I've tried and can't find a way how to list cron jobs. What other places than these can I look?

Comment: "it runs fine when started manually" means that you know what application it is. Please tell us, otherwise we can only guess and it will be difficult to help.

Comment: NetBeans (Oracle Java VM crash). VM downloaded myself and I use it all the time.

Comment: I don't use that program. Let us wait for someone who knows about it.

Comment: Systemd or /etc/crontab

Comment: Please explain how I can investigate systemd?

Comment: You can try using `journalctl -b` and page down until you find error messages that explain what is going on. Maybe grab a cup of coffee or tea first....